# scroll nav via onchange php

Tags: javascript, php

I'm not really that familiar with php so hence the question. I have a list of products that is dynamically created via php. When a user clicks one of the generated lists it sorts the products. I also want to move the user to a new part of the page to see the results. I thought I could do this via an smooth scroll using an onchange, but I'm not that sure where to put it. Site is bootstrap so was going to use the scrolling-nav.js.

here is the php generating the list

```
<?php
echo '<div id="brands">';
   //   echo $product['name'].'<br>';
      echo '<a href="#top-of-products"><input style="display:none"
            type="checkbox" data-type="brand" onchange="showlist(this)" 
            id="b-'.$brand['id'].'" name="'.$brand['name'].'" 
            value="'.$brand['name'].'"><label id="b-'.$brand['id'].'" 
            for="'.$brand['name'].'">'.$brand['name'].'</label></a><br>';
   } 
    echo '</div>';
```

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Is the results panel always in the same location on the page? If so, and you're using the jquery library, consider using jquery's scrollTop function:

```
$('#item).click(function(){
    $(html).scrollTop(val); //where val is the number of pixels hidden above the scrollable area when the Results panel is positioned where you want it to be
});
```

If the vertical position of the Results panel is variable, you can use this to define the "val" variable above:

```
$('#id-of-rewards-panel').offset().top
```

You might want to add a few pixels to that, because that will bring your element to the very top of the page

Comment: Not really as the links are in an accordion which will vary in size when opened depending on how many results the php delivers. One further twist is that I only need this to happen on mobiles. On desktops the accordion is in the sidebar, but on mobiles it's above the listed products

Comment: Okay, so it seems that the accordion varies in length, which means that the vertical position of the results panel is variable. If so, I think retrieving the offset via .offset().top should work

Comment: Hi. You could be right but I have no idea where to put that or how to implement it. Where in my php code would it go?

Comment: Sorry - missed the second half of your question (about mobile). There are a few ways to detect a mobile device via javascript - by browser (not the best, because new browser development will break your code), testing for touch events, detecting if an element whose display is set by a css media query is visible, detecting screen width, etc.

Comment: It wouldn't go in your php code, it would go in your javascript. You mentioned "change", so it looks like you've installed jquery. To use offset, you have to first use a selector to select your Results panel container, $('#id-of-rewards-panel') or $('.class-of-rewards-panel) if the class is unique. Then chain that with .offset().top ,which will detect the top-vertical offset.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. Sorry to be a bit of a noob, but I only really understand CSS/HTML. The mobile thing is fine. The site is bootstrap and goes mobile very nicely. The issue is that this scroll nav only needs to be active on mobiles as on desktops the sorting list is in a sidebar. On mobiles it's in a collapsed accordion above the results. When the accordion is open and a user clicks to make a selection I need the page to scroll down to the top of the results. The id of the div it needs to go to is "sort-box"

Comment: I think I do understand what you're trying to do, but I don't think you can do it with only php, HTML, & CSS. You have to use Javascript to detect the user's interactions with the browser, and my suggestion includes using Jquery, a javascript library.To start using Javascript, add a script tag in your page header (actually, for performance reasons, you might want to add it after the </body> tag) that links to a javascript file: <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/js/file.js"></script>.

Comment: If you'd like to use jquery, place this script tag in your php page above that one: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>. Then, check out these docs on how to use jquery: [link](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: Hi. There is jquery on the site, lots of it doing various things.  I just don't know how to create a new function and how to link it to the php function to achieve what I want.

Comment: Great! Just keep in mind that javascript doesn't really link to php persay. Php changes or produces content in the DOM (Document Object Model) and Javascript lets the user manipulate the DOM. First, pick a class name (we'll call it myClass for this example, and add that class to every element (div, p, etc.) which the user will click to scroll down to the Results container. To create your javascript function, open your javascript file, and (again, assuming you're using jquery) type $('#myClass').click(function(){var scrollTo = $('#buttonreplacement).offset().top; $(html).scrollTop(scrollTo);});

Comment: Also, typically, handlers (functions that listen for user actions, like $('#id').click) should only collect information about the user's actions, and then route that information to a function it then calls, but for simplicity, I wrapped up all of the scrolling functionality in to the click handler

Comment: Could I just drop this bit of js in the footer of the page in between <script></script> tags? The div that contains the php function is "panel-body" and on further investigation the div it needs to show after click is "sort-box". So I have amended your code as follows. $('#panel-body').click(function(){var scrollTo = $('#sort-box).offset().top; $(html).scrollTop(scrollTo);});

Also is there a ' missing after '#sort-box  there wasn't one in your code?

Comment: It will work if you put it in script tags in your html document, but it's generally better to separate it out into a different file just so you can keep your code better compartmentalized. Yes, good catch, there was a missing apostrophe. Also, check out Developer Tools on your Chrome Browser, or the Firebug add-on on Firefox - both will help you spot errors like missing apostrophes very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You put short stretch of your code, but, I see a `}` lost before the last line.
I guess you put your code for scrolling a new part of the page in `showlist()` javascript function.
But, I don't know if `onchange` method is the better. I would use `onclick` method

Comment: just realised I didn't post the full code. Here it is.

    <?php  foreach($view->brandfromcategory_data as $brand) {
         echo '<div id="brands">';
    //   echo $product['name'].'<br>';
       echo '<a href="#top-of-products"><input style="display:none" type="checkbox" data-type="brand" onchange="showlist(this)" "scrollTo(#buttonreplacement)" id="b-'.$brand['id'].'" name="'.$brand['name'].'" value="'.$brand['name'].'"><label id="b-'.$brand['id'].'" for="'.$brand['name'].'">'.$brand['name'].'</label></a><br>';
    } 
     echo '</div>';
    ?>

Comment: How says @ManGI1, try use click method with jquery to scroll

Answer (score 0):

here is the whole code:

```
<?php    foreach($view->brandfromcategory_data as $brand) {
        echo '<div id="brands">';
   //   echo $product['name'].'<br>';
      echo '<a href="#top-of-products"><input style="display:none" type="checkbox" data-type="brand" onchange="showlist(this)" "scrollTo(#buttonreplacement)" id="b-'.$brand['id'].'" name="'.$brand['name'].'" value="'.$brand['name'].'"><label id="b-'.$brand['id'].'" for="'.$brand['name'].'">'.$brand['name'].'</label></a><br>';
   } 
    echo '</div>';
   ?>
```

Comment: I want to go to the id "buttonreplacement'